# "they were lost" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "We're going to have to try and tackle him," he whispered to Ron. They had no choice: the moment anyone entered the room and saw the absence of three prisoners, **they were lost**. "Leave the lights on," Harry added, ...
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

What does "they were lost" mean in this context? Is it *they were dead* or something? It doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: I don't get the "absence of three prisoners" thing. Didn't 4 prisoners escape (Dobby, Luna, Dean, and Ollivander)? In Collins, one meaning of "lost" is "destroyed physically" (no. 6 BrE) and "destroyed or ruined physically or morally" (no. 1a AmE).

Comment: @AIQ, Dobby is not a prisoner. He was the one to come to rescue them.

Comment: @AIQ, if it means "destroyed physically", I think it should be *they would be lost*, shouldn't it?

Comment: Let's ignore "lost" for a moment and replace it with "dead". *"the moment anyone entered the room and saw the absence of three prisoners, they **were** dead"* is valid. It's like saying *"the moment I find out you are cheating on her, you **are** a dead man"* or *"when you hear an explosion, it is time!"* That construction is fine. Not sure why the author finds it exciting to write like this - "lost". It certainly isn't fun to read. Others may disagree.

Comment: @AIQ Yeah, that 'lost' made me lost. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they were dead or something?

Yes. Maybe not dead but in a whole lot of trouble. Their captors would know there was a way out, probably furious and afraid of what would happen if Voldemort found out. It would have been a lot easier if the escape had been quiet, that would have given the people remaining behind more time to prepare.